# Name of the part that holds the "fruit" and "twig" together

Tags: word-request

I cannot seem to find the name of the **part of a fruit tree which holds the "fruit" and the "twig" together that sometimes comes off with the fruit when we pluck the fruit.**

Can I call it **twig?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Are you thinking of the [stem](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stem)?

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that this part is also called "stem". I knewthat only the main part of a plantis called stem.

Comment: I should have called it **the stalk**    https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stalk

Comment: Stalk, stem, both OK.